# Changed the springframework.version to 5.3.23, the web application didn't work: 'NoSuchMethodError': CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have to use spring framework, spring security and web.xml (not spring boot) in order to make web application.
When I used springframework.version 5.2.20.RELEASE, the application worked well.
But, when I changed the springframework.version to 5.3.1, the web application didn't work and I received the following error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.<clinit>(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 53 more
```

The link of Github is as follows:
[spring-mvc-demo](https://github.com/sjm2932/spring-mvc-demo/)

Currently the springframework.version is 5.3.1 and it will not work properly.
If you change the springframework.version to 5.2.20.RELEASE, it will work.

Would you please advise me on how to resolve the issue?

The spring MVC application need to work properly with the springframework version 5.3.x(the target version is 5.3.23)

Comment: This error comes from mixing jars from different versions of Spring. YOu are probably upgrading a part of the app and not all Spring related jars to the new version, hence errors. Both Spring Security and Spring Data pull in different Spring versions hence errors, you cannot use Spring Data JPA 3.0.0 as that requires Spring 6 (which thus will pull in conflicting dependencies etc.). Spring Security 5.4.x is build against Spring 5.2 so that will pull in older dependencies and might not be compatible with Spring 5.3.

Comment: Thanks! Deinum
I didn't realize I was using 'spring-data-jpa'. When I removed  'spring-data-jpa' in the pom.xml file, and I received the following error. Would you please provide any advice on it?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: I strongly suggest a `mvn dependency:tree` and check your dependencies. I would really recommend to use Spring Boot even if it is just for managing the proper dependencies.

Comment: Hi! Deinum
I have to use spring mvc and web.xml in my project. Otherwise, I need to change a lot.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where did I state you should remove the `web.xml`, nowhere. Also changing a lot is subjective, as the only thing you would need to do is use the `SpringBootServletInitializer` and ditch the `web.xml` everything else can stay the same. So I don't state that that is a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks! Denium
My final target is not this project and the target project is much more complicated and has lots of dependencies. But, although it's hard for me to change the project using SpringBootServletInitializer, I will try to change the project using SpringBootServletInitializer. Thanks!

Comment: As stated you don't have to use Spring Boot, you can also only use the starters for dependency management, that way you at least have the proper non conflicting dependencies. And it really isn't any harder then changing to that class. You can use `@Import` and/or `@ImportResource` to load your existing configuration, you can just reuse everything yuo have now as is and later migrate to full blown Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! Denium
I will try to change the project using SpringBootServletInitializer as you said. If I have a question, is it better to make a new question?

Comment: Different questions should always be new questions and not comments. Also use the search as a lot has already been answered.

Comment: Hi! Deinum
Sorry! I checked the log messages again before using SpringBootServletInitializer. I saw the same error 'NoSuchMethodError': CorsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern.  I missed the message before.